# get value within rails scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, time, scope

I want to create a scope, I want to get all Orders in which has passed more than 24hrs since the last time they were updated.

I want to get all those Orders for then loop in them:

```
Order.more_than_24_updated.find_each do |order|
  #do some stuff with each order
end
```

I do not know how to add 24hrs to the `updated_at attribute` of orders in the scope:

```
scope :more_than_24_updated, -> { where(status: "pago_pendiente").where('#{Time.now} >= ?', updated_at + 24.hours) }
```

Well I know the above does not work, but well... how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
scope :more_than_24_updated, -> {where('status = ? and updated_at <= ?', :pago_pendiente, 24.hours.ago)}
```

Comment: Yes, <= is inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one

```
scope :more_than_24_updated, -> { where(status: "pago_pendiente").where("NOW() - '24 hours'::INTERVAL >= updated_at") }
```

Comment: Well this answer is ok, but it has some issues with postgresql, in my case I use mysql in local and postgresql in production, so this solution is not very practical for me, however thank you very much.